# References for a certain generalization of Hochschild cohomology?

Tags: homological-algebra, topological-quantum-field-theory, derived-categories, hochschild-homology, reference-request

Let $C$ be an algebra.  Let $E = C^{\otimes 2n}$ be the tensor product (over the ground field) of $2n$ copies of $C$.  [EDIT: Or better, $E = C\otimes C^{op}\otimes C\otimes C^{op}\cdots\otimes C \otimes C^{op}\quad$ ($2n$ copies of $C$, half of them "op").]

Let $F_{even}$ be the $E$ module with underlying vector space $C^{\otimes n}$, where the $(2i)$-th factor of $E$ acts on the left side of the $i$-th factor of $F_{even}$, and the $(2i+1)$-th factor of $E$ acts on the right side (i.e. left action of $C^{op}$) of the $i$-th factor of $F_{even}$.  ($0 \le i \le n-1$ .)

Define $F_{odd}$ similarly (same underlying vector space $C^{\otimes n}$), but with the $(2i)$-th factor of $E$ acting on the left side of the $i$-th factor of $F_{odd}$, and the $(2i+1)$-th factor of $E$ acting on the right side of the 
$(i+1)$-th (modulo $n$) factor of $F_{odd}$.  (Note that "modulo $n$" means the $n$-th factor is the 0-th factor.)

I'm interested in the derived $Hom_E(F_{even}, F_{odd})$.  We can think of this as living in a disk with its boundary divided into $2n$ segments, alternating between incoming and outgoing segments.  For $n=1$ this is just the Hochschild cohomology of $C$.  For $n=2$ it's what one might associate to a saddle bordism in a 1+1-dimensional TQFT, or rather, the space in which the TQFT invariant of the saddle bordism lives.

Does $Hom_E(F_{even}, F_{odd})$ have a name?  Is it mentioned in the literature anywhere?

Comment: I'm confused; don't you need some of the copies of C in E to be opposite algebras, or have an involution, in order to have it act on the right-hand sides?

Comment: Yes, good point.  I'll edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: In what you just edited you have a direct product of algebras where it should be tensor product.

Comment: Now I'm confused. I don't think you need to involve the opposite algebra, since it makes perfect sense to let C act on C from the right. In general you would need to have the opposite algebra in there, but C is naturally a right C-module as well as a left C-module. Another thing, if you change it to C \otimes C^op \otimes... etc, then the definition of F_even doesn't really make sense, does it? Now you have the opposite algebra acting from the right, which is the same as the original algebra acting from the left, so for the i-th guy in C^{\otimes n} you have two copies of C acting on the left.

Comment: And similarly for F_odd.

Comment: If I write things like $Hom_E$, then I need some factors of $C^{op}$, since the notation implies I'm viewing $F_{even}$ and $F_{odd}$ as left $E$-modules.  As to the other point, perhaps my terminology is non-standard.  It seems natural to me to say that if $M$ is a $C$-$C$ bimodule, i.e. a left $C\times C^{op}$ module, then $C$ acts on the left side of $M$ and $C^{op}$ acts on the right side of $M$ (which is not the same thing as saying that $M$ is a right $C^{op}$ module).

Comment: But if people find the original question confusing then I'm happy to edit it again.

Comment: Ok, just a misunderstanding. I personally read "M is a right C^{op}-module" when I see "C^{op} acts on M on the right", but that could very well not be the common way of reading this. 
But I still think there is a typo in the second line where you use direct products instead of tensor products.

Comment: One more thing. I think there might be some issue with indexing. You say you index the n copies with i going from 0 to n-1. Now in the definition of F_odd you let the rightmost copy of C^op in E act on copy number n in the C^n. I hope you see what I mean, despite my efforts ;) Just take n=1 and you should have C^op acting on copy number 1 in the module, but the module consists only of one copy of C numbered by 0. 
 

Comment: But 1 = 0, modulo 1.  More generally, when I write "modulo n" in the definition of `F_odd`, I mean to identity the n-th copy of C with the 0-th copy of C.  So there's an cyclic symmetry to the whole thing.

Comment: ok sorry my bad, missed the modulo n part. Now I think I understand, thanks.

Comment: I made more clarifications in response to your comments -- thanks.

Comment: My vague feeling is that I've never seen this definition before, and certainly don't have a name for it.  If C is commutative it can be expressed as derived mapping out of Hochschild homology, but that's all I know.

Comment: Thanks -- the negative answer is useful.  It means I'll spend more time doing calculations and less time searching the literature.